# How to create a document in FaunaDB with a given _id using GraphQL instead of accepting the auto-generated one

Tags: graphql, primary-key, faunadb

It is possible to do it using FQL, but I can't find any example of a GraphQL mutation that creates a new document in FaunaDB where the _id is defined by the application and not by FaunaDB itself.

Of course I can add my application-generated ID (an uuidv4 for instance) as an additional attribute in the document and create an index for it, but it doesn't seem right considering the document will have another primary key anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [resolver](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/directives/d_resolver) directive, associate with a user defined function (UDF) to accept `_id`  as a parameter and then use `Create`.

Here is an example,

**Schema file**

```
type Order {
  customerName: String!
  price: Float!
}

input OrderInput {
  orderID: Int!
  customerName: String!
  price: Float!
}

type Query {
  CreateOrder(data: OrderInput!): Order! @resolver
}
```

**UDF (CreateOrder)**

```
Update(
  Function("CreateOrder"),
  {
  body: Query(Lambda(["orderdata"],
  Create(Ref(Collection("Order"), Select(["orderID"],Var("orderdata"))),
  {
    data: {
      customerName: Select(["customerName"], Var("orderdata")),
      price: Select(["price"], Var("orderdata"))
    }
  }
)))})
```

**GraphQL Query**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Jay. In a scenario where an Order has an actual relation with a Customer then I guess I would have to manually include an OrderCustomerRelation input definition into my schema, is that right? Would that be all? My concern is in the line of the metaphor of asking for a banana but end up having to bring in the gorilla and the entire jungle.